# What is the jsonnet syntax for nested arrays?

Tags: gitlab-ci, jsonnet

I cannot find the way to declare an array in an array with jsonnet. Here is the syntax I would like to render:

```
git/push/myrules:
  rules:
      - changes:
        - package.json
        - yarn.lock
```

I do succeed to setup **changes** as the first element of **rules** array

```
local git_push_instance() =
  {
    ['rules']: [
        'changes'
    ]
  };

{
  ['git/push/myrules']: git_push_instance()
}
```

Here is the output of command line **jsonnet rules.jsonnet**

```
{
   "git/push/myrules": {
      "rules": [
         "changes"
      ]
   }
}
```

But how to setup changes as an array with 2 entries : package.json and yarn.lock ?

I try this but got an error:

```
local git_push_instance() =
  {
    ['rules']: [
        changes: ['package.json', 'yarn.lock']
    ]
  };

{
  ['git/push/myrules']: git_push_instance()
}
```

> STATIC ERROR: rules.jsonnet:4:16: expected a comma before next array
> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that below construct has a *key* (`changes:`) while supposedly being an array entry:

```jsonnet
    ['rules']: [
        changes: ['package.json', 'yarn.lock'] // incorrect
    ]
```

You need to change the above to emit an array of (mini)objects instead:

```jsonnet
    ['rules']: [
        { changes: ['package.json', 'yarn.lock'] },
    ]
```

Just for completeness, pasting below the src and its output:

### rules.jsonnet

```jsonnet
local git_push_instance() =
  {
    rules: [
      { changes: ['package.json', 'yarn.lock'] },
    ],
  };

{
  'git/push/myrules': git_push_instance(),
}
```

### output

NB: piping it thru `yq -PI2` for a cleaner YAML output:

```yaml
$ jsonnet rules.jsonnet | yq -PI2
git/push/myrules:
  rules:
    - changes:
        - package.json
        - yarn.lock
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @jjo
I would had never imagined this kind of solution since {} was a dict in my mind  ... actually it is an object as stated in jsonnet survival kit : https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/jsonnet/

Comment: You're welcome!, mind that a jsonnet object is pretty similar/same to a dict in other languages (like python), and the issue stands: there you need to provide an array of elements (indexed by their e.g. `[0]`, `[1]` ... indexes), each element in turn is an object (~dict). PS: appreciate if you can mark it as answered/resolved, to also help others with this result. Thanks!